# Docker entrypoint permission denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-entrypoint

I am currently trying to deal with a deployment to a kubernetes cluster. The deployment keeps failing with the response

```
 Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"
```

I have tried to change the permissions on the file which seem to succeed as if I ls -l I get -rwxr-xr-x as the permissions for the file.

I have tried placing the chmod command both in the dockerfile itself and prior to the image being built and uploaded but neither seems to make any difference.
Any ideas why I am still getting the error?

dockerfile below

```
FROM node:10.15.0
CMD []
ENV NODE_PATH /opt/node_modules

# Add kraken files
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kraken
ADD .  /opt/kraken/
# RUN chown -R node /opt/
WORKDIR /opt/kraken

RUN npm install && \
    npm run build && \
    npm prune --production

# Add the entrypoint
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
USER node
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: Here, some tasks of a certain sequence are needed to be done. Give proper permission to `/entrypoint.sh` file in the dockerfile, build it, push it, if the imagePullPolicy is set"IfNotPresent" then update the image with the new one, and deploy

Comment: Can you provide your podTemplate?

Comment: Op, clear the requirments, those are needed to explain what you have done better.

Comment: @tacoofdoomk Are you using minikube or other cluster?

Answer (score 11):

This error is not about entrypoint error but command inside. Always start scripts with "sh script.sh" either entrypoint or cmd. In this case it would be: ENTRYPOINT ["sh",  "entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]` and `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]` are the same. So no need to do so.

Comment: Absolutely not same, one requires executable permission and one doesn't need. Just try and figure it out.

Comment: Then one has to insert `!#/bin/bash` or `!#/bin/sh` at the begining of the script. And how do you know that the script file has no this line

Comment: Well if you don't add that line you are in absolute disaster state. Your script's behaviour won't be same between environments and consistent, if you don't follow first rule of the bash script then it is your choice.

Comment: So, you can not tell that the script has no such line. And if thats true, prepending 'sh' in the ENTRYPOINT is not necessary and this is not the solution.

Comment: What type of arguments are you continuing?

Answer (score -1):

I created a github action with a Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh file. I run command 'chmod +x' in my computer and push to github repository. I did not RUN 'chmod +x' in Dockerfile. It works.

Answer (score -2):

tray docker exec -it    /bin/sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).